# Red Cherry Shrimp tank mates

Tags: aquarium, community-aquarium

In our tank of 120 liters we have a starting colony of [Red Cherry Shrimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_shrimp), 4 adults and a growing number of smaller ones. They all live in a big pile of (curly) java moss. There are quite a bit of other plants and some wood.

As tank mates they have:

- 4 [Japonica Amano Shrimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caridina_multidentata) (adults)
- 2 Pleco's
- 6 Panda Corydoras
- 8 Cardinal Tetra's
- Unknown number of [Assassin snails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clea_helena)

I am thinking about swapping the Cardinal Tetra's for an other species, one that can preferably breed.

What is are good tank mate for this setup?

Comment: What ever you do, do NOT add cichlids to the mix. They will eat your shrimp. Even the little cichlids will do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got a very similar setup as you have:

- 180 litre tank
- 11 Panda corries
- 17 Cardinal Tetras
- 4 big platy & some little ones (2 Platy Hawii, 2 'mixed')
- Cherry shrimp

I chose the platy's because they have similar requirements as the other fish (e.g. regarding temperature), also because they're easy to breed, and they will basically swim in all layers of the tank (top, middle, bottom). 
 
Other fish I have considered are guppies, but decided not to take them because they breed too fast. 
Even with the platy's, I think eventually I will have to sell some, but so far I don't think my tank is overstocked. 
Another fish you can consider is a betta. If you want them to breed you should get a male and 2 or 3 females.
Before the platys, I also had one. But after it died (from old age), I decided not to get one again, because I've got a bit too much current in my tank.

One thing you have to keep in mind is that **fish eat shrimp**. 
 If you only have 4 adults now, it's possible that they won't be able to keep the population stable or get it growing, and that you won't have any left in 6 months. 
 But it does sound like they have quit some hiding places, so it might work. 
I started with 10-15 shrimp about a year ago, and the population seems stable/growing (I definitely have more than 15 now). But I also have a lot of hiding places.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 40 liter tank, I understand that my tank is a different set up...
6 red cherry shrimp
1 fire red shrimp,
2 yellow Sunkist shrimp
3 blue velvets shrimp
1 oil Tatia catfish
3 cardinal tetras
And I have had 3 pregnant shrimp in only 2 months, and no harm has been brought by the cardinal tetras, but I think they won’t harm any baby shrimp. I think your current set up is fine, and your tank having wood and moss is definitely a great aquascape for a breeding tank, but my tank is only 40 gallons and they aren’t at full size due to the tank, I do know that previously my Otto catfish has killed 6 of my shrimps even if they said they were shrimp friendly, so I understand why you want to change the cardinal tetras, maybe micro fish?

A good ratio if there is 5 shrimp is 2 males for every 3 females. 2:3. I have my fish tank set up like that, and I suddenly noticed many females carrying eggs around the tank.

I do wish you luck on that red cherry colony!